# Unable to populate PowerPoint TextBox with value in Excel cell using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, textbox, powerpoint

It's all fixed now..I had forgotten I had used an activex control textbox not the "normal" PPT textbox. This is the correct basic code to populate a single textbox.

Thanks to David Zemens I got through some early issues I was having, but I still can't accomplish my end goal. He felt it was best to start a new thread so here it is.

The first thing I do is open the PPT file and duplicate the first slide. The duplicate method was replicating the slide, but was causing other issues, so Dave me a workaroundchange they way I copy the main slide. Below is the code I have written, which will not compile for the moment. (Also I've modified to just write to one textbox rather than use the looping which will eventually be done once I get one to work)

Any advice would be helpful. Please let me know if you need additional info and thanks!

valppt()

```
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim newslide As PowerPoint.SlideRange
Dim slideCtr As Integer
Dim tb As PowerPoint.Shape
Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PPT.Visible = True

PPT.Presentations.Open ("C:\Documents\createqchart.pptx")

Range("F2").Activate
slideCtr = 1

Set newslide = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(slideCtr).Duplicate
Set tb = newslide.Shapes("TextBox" & slideCtr)

slideCtr = slideCtr + 1

Do Until slideCtr > 2
    If slideCtr = 2 Then
       'tb.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = Format(ActiveCell.Value, "m/d/yyyy")
       tb.OLEFormat.Object.Value = Format(ActiveCell.Value, "m/d/yyyy")
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    slideCtr = slideCtr + 1

    If slideCtr = 38 Then
        Set newslide = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(slideCtr).Duplicate
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -25).Activate
    End If

Loop
```

End Sub

Comment: The correct code is now in the original question. I had forgotten I had used an activex textbox rather than a normal textbox.

Comment: Hi again! Which line is causing an error for you? I notice that the default naming convention for textboxes is like `TextBox 1` but the way you are assigning them, it's `TextBox1`. That would cause an error for sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct code.

```
Sub valppt()
Dim PPT As PowerPoint.Application
Dim newslide As PowerPoint.SlideRange
Dim slideCtr As Integer
Dim tb As PowerPoint.Shape
Set PPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PPT.Visible = True

PPT.Presentations.Open ("C:\Documents\createqchart.pptx")

Range("F2").Activate
slideCtr = 1

Set newslide = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(slideCtr).Duplicate
Set tb = newslide.Shapes("TextBox" & slideCtr)

slideCtr = slideCtr + 1

Do Until slideCtr > 2
    If slideCtr = 2 Then
       'tb.TextFrame.TextRange.Characters.Text = Format(ActiveCell.Value, "m/d/yyyy")
       tb.OLEFormat.Object.Value = Format(ActiveCell.Value, "m/d/yyyy")
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    slideCtr = slideCtr + 1

    If slideCtr = 38 Then
        Set newslide = PPT.ActivePresentation.Slides(slideCtr).Duplicate
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, -25).Activate
    End If

Loop
End Sub
```